# Something wrong with my animation but I don't know what it is

Tags: unity

I am new to Blender and I am using it with Unity, so I made a simple animation but I have problems when I import it to Unity.

One of the two objects does not move and i dont know why. In Blender, the animation works fine but I must have done something wrong, otherwise it would look good in Unity.

Unity shows 4 clips with different animations data and I dont know why. I am using FBX format.

I attach the file in case someone has time to give it a look, since I'm stuck in my project and do not know what to do.

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wz6d6MBO3zl_pbGEsWJMm1Eva330Ikxr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Every object has its own action and fbx can handle them but it not work well in Unity. To merge the animations in the fbx exporter window at the bottom left corner click on the "Animation" tab and disable "All actions" and "NLA Strips".

Comment: Not 100% positive but i think this actually works. I need to do more testing. Thanks by the way!